# preg_match and images URL

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a little problem with `preg_match` function in PHP. I think that I never will learn how to use this function. I want to extract URL of image from HTML without name of image. For example, if I have some link for image:

```
"/data/images/2013-10-03/someimage.jpg"
```

or

```
"http://something.com//data/images/2013-10-03/someimage.jpg"
```

How can I use `preg_match` function to delete everything left of last forward slash, so I can get only image name from URL?

Maybe it's smarter to use different function but I dont know which one?

P.S. Can you give me some good tutorial for `preg_match` function?

Maybe I forgot to say... I dont know how long is image name or what is image name exactly. I need function for extract only what is on right side from last forward slash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$pattern = '/[\w\-]+\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)/';
$subject = 'http://something.com//data/images/2013-10-03/someimage.png';
$result = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo $matches[0]; //someimage.jpg
```

Answer (score 6):

No need for regex or anything fancy:

```
$var = "http://something.com/data/images/2013-10-03/someimage.jpg";

$image = basename($var);
```

Answer (score 1):

U need use `preg_replace()` and u can try use online for play with regular, it is a fast way to learn regex.  http://preg_replace.onlinephpfunctions.com/

For example: `/\/someimage.jpg/` replace on `''`(null).

It will return http://something.com//data/images/2013-10-03 from http://something.com//data/images/2013-10-03/someimage.jpg.

Comment: Hm... I think that I dont understand you...or you dont understand me :)

I need function for extracting image name from url. So if I have something like this:
http://something.com//data/images/2013-10-03/someimage.jpg.
Function must return only "someimage.jpg"

Comment: Maybe I forgot to say...I dont know exactly what is image name or how many chars have name...I only need what is right from last forward slash...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Simple HTML DOM Parser to get href between the a tags.
For example:

foreach($html->find('a.[class="your class"]') as $var) 
      // echo "href." >sometext
";

hope this helps!

Comment: No, I don't need that :) I need some image name extractor from url